# Refresh Chart Every Second

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Have a question. I think it must be quite easy to implement but for some reason I can't do it. Right now the charts are updated if I click on them. I wish that they were updated every time I change a value (just like in Excel), for must be easier to implement a timer.

For some reason I can't implement it and I have already tried a few things that I have found online.
I have two charts and I want the charts to update the values every second (or the interval suitable for the program).

I am working on a Windows form and have the following VB code:

```
Private Sub Chart1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseClick

    AutoSize = False
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 0.05
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 200
    With Chart1
        .Series(0).Points.Clear()
        .Series(1).Points.Clear()
        .Series(2).Points.Clear()
    End With
    With Chart1
        .Series(0).Points.AddXY(TOCGLong, TOSumMassValues)
        .Series(1).Points.AddXY(LandCGLong, LandSumMassValues)
        .Series(2).Points.AddXY(ZFWCGLong, ZFWSumMassValues)
    End With
    With Chart1.ChartAreas
        With .Max
            .AxisX.Maximum = 3.55
            .AxisY.Maximum = 2300
        End With
        With .Min
            .AxisX.Minimum = 3.15
            .AxisY.Minimum = 1200
        End With
    End With

    Chart1.Series(3).Points.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        Chart1.Series(3).Points.AddXY(CGLimitX(i), CGLimitY(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Chart3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Chart3.MouseClick
    Dim FuelX() As Integer = {80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180}
    Dim ISA() As Double = {27171.16, 24053.39, 21011, 18043.99, 15152.36, 12336.11, 9595.24, 6929.75, 4339.64, 1824.91, -614.44}
    Dim ISA20() As Double = {25421.84, 21987.56, 18644, 15409.16, 12277.04, 9247.64, 6320.96, 3497, 775.76, -1842.76, -4358.56}
    Dim ISA35() As Double = {23726.04, 19793.81, 16041, 12467.61, 9073.64, 5859.09, 2823.96, -31.75, -2708.04, -5204.91, -7522.36}

    AutoSize = False
    Chart3.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 10
    Chart3.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 5000
    With Chart3
        .Series(0).Points.Clear()
        '.Series(1).Points.Clear()
        '.Series(2).Points.Clear()
    End With
    With Chart3
        .Series(0).Points.AddXY(FuelConsuption, SDaltitude.Value)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            .Series(1).Points.AddXY(FuelX(i), ISA(i))
            .Series(2).Points.AddXY(FuelX(i), ISA20(i))
            .Series(3).Points.AddXY(FuelX(i), ISA35(i))
        Next
    End With
    With Chart3.ChartAreas
        With .Max
            .AxisX.Maximum = 180
            .AxisY.Maximum = 23000
        End With
        With .Min
            .AxisX.Minimum = 80
            .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: how do update your chart exactly ? and `for some reason,i can't implement a timer`,why ?

Comment: Hi @zackraiyan . The chart is updated with new values inserted in Text Boxes. Those values in those arrays are only the initial set of values.
I don't fully understand the implementation of a timer plus a chart update. Thank you,

Comment: show the code that update the chart ..

Comment: do you realize you won't be able to do much else, if anything at all, in that instance of the application, while your timer is running?  Also, this is Excel VBA, correct?  Where does VS come into the picture?

Comment: @ashleedawg no, it is not Excel VBA. It is VB. What I am trying to achieve is that each time a specific textbox has its value changed, the chart updates respectively. As I can't find a way to implement this, I thought of a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the code out of the Chart1.MouseClick handler and put it in a Sub of its own with a descriptive name. Do the same for the Chart3.MouseClick handler.

In the Chart1.MouseClick handler, call that first Sub.

In the Chart3.MouseClick handler, call that second method.

**For the question in the question:**

> I wish that they were updated everytime I change a value

In the appropriate textbox [`leave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx) handlers, call the appropriate method(s), something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    UpdateChart1()
    UpdateChart2()
End Sub
```

I suggest using the Leave event so that it doesn't keep changing while the user is in the middle of typing.

**For the question in the title**:

You should put the chart updating code in its own methods, as written above. Then you can easily call it from a timer's tick event. The essential parts of the code are like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim tim As Timer

    Sub UpdateMpgChart()
        ' ... code here to update the chart

    End Sub

    Sub UpdateOtherChart()
        ' ... code here to update the other chart
    End Sub

    Sub TimerTickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        UpdateMpgChart()
        UpdateOtherChart()

    End Sub

    Sub InitialiseTimer()
        tim = New Timer With {.Interval = 1000}
        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf TimerTickHandler
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitialiseTimer()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If tim IsNot Nothing Then
            tim.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Morton. Is there a way to make the Chart 1 and Chart 2, update/refresh each time a textbox1 and textbox2 values are changed?

Comment: Yes, that is described in the first part of my answer.

Comment: @Focha I added an example of using a Textbox.Leave event.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish that they were updated every time I change a value (just like in Excel), for must be easier to implement a timer.

You can use the ReactiveProperty [nuget](https://github.com/runceel/ReactiveProperty).

You declare a ReactiveProperty for each value you want to "react":

```
public ReactiveProperty<int> Prop1 = new ReactiveProperty(0);
public ReactiveProperty<int> Prop2 = new ReactiveProperty(0);
```

In the constructor (or load event) just tell the property to update the chart:

```
Prop1.Subscribe(value => Chart1_Click(this, null));
```

Here I'm telling to Prop1 to execute the Chart1_Click method, but you can create an specific method for updating the charts and put this in the subscribe method instead the Chart1_Click.

And for change the Prop1 or Prop2 values just:

```
Prop1.Value = 5; // this line will run the specified method
Prop2.Value = 10;
```